# does chrome ignore confirm dialog sometimes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='a.html' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">test</a>
</body>
```

when I choose no, chrome still goes to the page a.html, but strangely sometimes it behaves right, stop navigating to the new page, I don't know why, is this a chrome bug?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7 and Chrome 16.0.912.41 beta, other browsers (safari, firefox) works fine.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqWKv/). Can't reproduce in Chrome 15.0.874.121 m. Is there any more code involved? Which extensions do you have installed in Chrome?

Comment: thank you for you hint, i find it is extension Google Dictionary (by Google)3.0.6 cause this bug, when i remove this extension, chrome behaves right!

Comment: Be sure to file a bug report with them, then. Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Chrome 16 beta: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100401

Should be fixed soon.

Comment: Still not fixed I believe.